# Concatenate columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate several columns in one

dataframe:

```
df

   One  Two
0    a    d
1    b    e
2    c    f
```

I tried:

```
df['all_columns'] = df.apply(''.join, axis = 1)
```

Error:

> TypeError: ('sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index 0')

I expected:

```
df

   all_columns  
0            a    
1            b    
2            c    
3            d
4            e
5            f
```

I'm trying a solution without having to use the name of my columns because their names are very large

Answer (score 3):

### `pd.concat`

```
# @piR's magic
pd.concat(map(df.get, df), ignore_index=True).to_frame('all_cols')

  all_cols
0        a
1        b
2        c
3        d
4        e
5        f
```

More `concat` options:

```
pd.concat(dict(df.items()), ignore_index=True).to_frame('all_columns')
pd.concat({**df}, ignore_index=True).to_frame('all_columns')

  all_cols
0        a
1        b
2        c
0        d
1        e
2        f
```

---

### `ravel` + `DataFrame()` reconstruction

```
pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().ravel('F'), columns=['all_cols'])

  all_cols
0        a
1        b
2        c
3        d
4        e
5        f
```

---

### `melt` with housekeeping

```
df.melt(value_name='all_columns').drop('variable', 1)

  all_columns
0           a
1           b
2           c
3           d
4           e
5           f
```

Comment: `pd.concat` can take an iterable `pd.concat(map(df.get, df), ignore_index=True).to_frame('all_columns')`

Comment: Also, no need to transpose.  Use the fortran ordering `pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().ravel('F'), columns=['all_cols'])`

Comment: One more.  You can pass a dictionary to `pd.concat` but it won't interpret the dataframe in a dictionary context unless you force it.  `pd.concat({**df}, ignore_index=True).to_frame('all_columns')`

Comment: @WeNYoBen I went with the first options that came to mind but melt will work nicely ;) `df.melt(value_name='all_columns').drop('variable', 1)`  you should post it now

Comment: @cs95 no worry , you can just adding into yours :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need simple [**`unstack`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df.unstack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('allcolumns')
```

Output:

```
    allcolumns
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the stack/unstack family implement a lot of internal reshaping logic so are a bit slower than concat.

Answer (score 1):

So what I have understand you want to combine all column values into single column 
df

`Prefix Assignment  Tutorial    Midterm TakeHome  Final`
`5        57.14      34.09       64.38    51.48   52.50`
so final result should be 

final df

`all_columns`
`5`
`57.14`
`34.09`
`64.38`
`51.48`
`52.50`

you can do this:
`final_res = pd.DataFrame(data={"all_columns":list(df.values.flatten())})`